# Shared library to minimise size of FLA file

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

In a project we use large flash FLA file with lots of graphic assets, but the actual data that is changed is just in a few symbols. Sometimes it is not very efficient to transfer the whole FLA file that comes up to 20MB now.

I was thinking about using Shared Libraries, but it seems that, even if you import external library, it still copies the whole assets into the destination file, but does not link it from external file. Consequently, size of the FLA file still remains the same.

Is there any way to split FLA files into few separate in order to minimise size of the most frequently updated file and keep all unchanged data in another file?

Answer (score 0):

you can copy items into a swc file ([example link](http://flexion.wordpress.com/2007/06/27/building-flash-cs3-components/)) then link them to the project. If i were you id consider using a SVN client, that way you can upload/download only the changes made and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

External library is definitely the solution. Put all the assets in a new FLA (or vice-versa), export the SWC. After that import the SWC to the main FLA as 'runtime shared library', that way nothing gets included at runtime, you just need to make sure you preload the SWF (related to the SWC) before you start accessing the assets.